# AbstractJAXRS E No resource classes found : cxf 3.2.8 and websphere 9.0.5.3

Tags: rest, web-services, jax-rs, websphere

I'm using WebSphere 9.0.5.3 and after migrating CXF-core lib from 3.1.x to 3.2.x I'm facing this problem :

```
 AbstractJAXRS E   No resource classes found
```

with CXF 3.1.x everything works fine my server is working and my rest services are working as well.

> ps1: I have already disabled JAXRSEngine of WebSphere and working with my own libraries ( in the shared isolated package ) and as I said it was working fine with the previous version

> ps2: I have already modified the class loader policy ( Multiple -
> single )

with some debugging, I figured out that WebSphere is not even loading my classes ( annotated with @path)

> ps3: have already upgraded jaxrs-ws-rs to 2.1.1 because CXF 3.2.x
> supports JAX-RS latest 2.1 spec even though this spec is backward
> compatible with jaxrs 2.0
>
> and i have already upgraded also all the CXF JAXRS related jars and still have
> the same problem
>
> PS4: my application is working fine with tomcat 8 and Wildfly/JBoss so
> i don't think i have a problem with my resources classes

> PS5: in the same jar, the other classes are loaded so WebSphere is filtering the resources classes and not loading them

***the main problem here is why websphere is not loading my resouruce classes i have just upgraded the jar and I kept the old configurations ?***

Answer (score 1):

The IBM WebSphere Application Server does not provide direct support for JAXRS 2.1.  However, what you are attempting may still be possible.  Beyond setting the "com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRS20Engine" property to "true" you should also set the JAXRS provider to "2.0 spec" via the command prompt or administrative console, see the following for details: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rwbs_jaxrs_coexist.html

Beyond this, if you need the JAX-RS 2.1 APIs, then you will need to package the APIs with your application.  You might also need to use parent-last classloading or package them in an isolated shared library associated with your application.  Either approach poses some classloading risk.

Comment: i have already tried both jax-rs 2.0 spec and the default jax-rs 2.0 provider but still have the same problem ( question : can  jax-rs version have an effect on the class loading policy of websphere so it skips my resource classes while loading the application ?)

Comment: an is it okay to set jaxrs-2.0 spec while im providing jaxrs-2.1 jars in my application ?

Comment: Aziz, My initial answer was incorrect.  I have edited it with an option you may want to try.

Comment: so i have added CXF-libs under the ear , javax-ws-rs 2.1 jar under a shared lib , and i have set JAXRS-provider to be 2.0 spec but i still have the same problem am i missinf or doing something wrong ? ( ps changing the class loader policy lead to a lot of errors exemple  in my case  )

Comment: ps : i really think you for your help and quick responses

Comment: Just to confirm: You are setting the "com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRS20Engine" property to "true", not the ""com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine" property?  Also, changing the classloader to parent-last is a dicey thing to do so I'm not overly surprised this has given you other problems.  It may not be possible for you to move this application to JAXRS 2.1 without transitioning to WebSphere Liberty / Open Liberty.

Comment: yes i used "-Dcom.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRS20Engine" but i still have same problem ( no resource class found ) , are you sure there is no solution to use JAX RS 2.1 with WAS 9.0x ?

Comment: Lastly, you could try adding your resource classes via overriding the getClasses() method on your Application class.

Or, if you just want to move up to CXF 3.2.x but can remain on JAXRS 2.0, then remove the "DisableIBMJAXRS20Engine" property and use "2.0 spec" while packaging the CXF you want to use in your application.

Comment: Make sure that the JAX-RS API JARs are in an _isolated_ shared library - that will ensure that they are loaded before the JAX-RS APIs that WebSphere supplies.  Is your Application class getting loaded?  You may need to update (or create) your web.xml file - otherwise, the web container will not know that you have a JAX-RS implementation in your app.

Comment: hello @AndyMcCright can this be related to not load some classes by websphere i mean just a not compatible jax-rs API can lead to change a class loader policy and filter some classes

Comment: I have confirmed that the CXF jars must be included in an isolated shared library.  Simply including them in the lib directory of the .war file is not sufficient.  By setting up the isolated shared library, setting the "com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRS20Engine"  property to "true", and specifying the Application class in the web.xml I was able to run a simple JAXRS application with both CXF 3.1.18 and 3.2.10.

Comment: @Aziz my guess is that it never loaded the CXF 3.1.X classes in your app, but instead loaded those classes from WebSphere's copy (which is 3.1.18).  In order for the application classloader to load your copy of CXF (and the JAX-RS API classes), those binaries would either need to be in an isolated shared library in your app - so long as the app was configured for parent-last delegation.  Jim's suggestion about putting the JAX-RS 2.1 APIs and CXF 3.2.X jars into an isolated shared library is probably the best solution (also set the Disable switch and set "2.0.spec").  HTH

Comment: hello @AndyMcCright no it's not working i did what you said i added all the cxf lib under a shared package, ( i also disabled switch and seted 2.0 spec) but i still have the same problem "no ressource classes found"

Comment: @Aziz can you update the description with your current web.xml? Most likely you are missing some CXF configuration.  WebSphere provides this with the version of CXF that it packages, but if you want to use a different version, then you will need to configure it manually.  This page may help:  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesincontainerwithoutSpring